# Can an iPhone application be tested on carrier locked phones?

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing

Is it possible to test applications on carrier locked iphones? Can xcode connect carrier locked phones?
HELP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Almost all phones used to be "carrier locked". I have no idea what the state is today, but the question seems incomplete - as if there is a *real* restriction (eg. lack of network connectivity) not asked about.

Comment: Mike W unfortunately i m not that rich to take such type of risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it works correctly.

Been there, done that.